# Eclipse RCP - custom control/icon on tab

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I just started using Eclipse RCP to develop an application. I am completely new to this framework. Interface of the application is somewhat similiar to this:

[image: The interface]

OK, I already edited the picture to show what I need. Basically I have a class extending *DiagramEditor*. I have tabs and each of them is associated with background *Job*. Now I need to put some kind of icon or control inside the tab that indicates what is the status of the *Job*. How can I add something like this programatically and how can I bind it with *Job* status, so the icon changes simultaneously with it? I already know that *Job* allows to add *JobChangeListener* so I can perform some actions if the *Job* changes its state. The biggest problem is how to add some custom control (possibly wrapped in self-written class) to the tab. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Changing the tab requires writing a custom renderer which is not straightforward.

Comment: Could you recommend any articles or anything that could point me to right direction?

Comment: There isn't much about this. [This tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4Renderer/article.html) covers some basics, it is aimed at an e4 application but renderers should work for 3.x compatibility mode as well.

Comment: Thank you, sir, I'll take a look! Or maybe I'll try to come up with another solution if this one turns out to be too complicated.